# Merging one file to multiple rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes I would like to merge.

The first looks like this:

```
 Pig_no Pen       Date Group Sex  BW Treat_date
1      1  96 06.05.2019     1   m 7.1       23.05.2019
2      2  96 06.05.2019     1   m 7.6       24.05.2019
3      3  96 06.05.2019     1   m 7.4       NA
4      4  96 06.05.2019     1   m 6.0       12.06.2019
5      5  96 06.05.2019     1   m 7.0       02.06.2019
6      6  96 06.05.2019     1   m 6.9       NA
```

In this dataframe Pig_no is the experimental unit.

Then I have another dataframe on the same pigs looking like this, but here Pen is the experimental unit.

```
      Date       Treat_date Pen   
1     06.05.2019 25.05.2019 100 
2     06.05.2019 22.05.2019 106 
3     06.05.2019 27.05.2019 105       
4     24.06.2019 15.07.2019  50        
5     24.06.2019 07.08.2019  54        
6     24.06.2019 18.07.2019  67
```

I therefore have treat_date connected to a specific pen, and not pig_no.
When I try to merge the two documents normally,

```
merge2 <- merge(df1,df2, by=c("Pen","Date","Treat_date"), all=TRUE)

Pen       Date   Treat_date  Pig_no 
1   1 03.01.2020 15.01.2020  10555     
2   1 03.01.2020       <NA>  10560     
3   1 03.01.2020       <NA>  10583     
4   1 03.01.2020       <NA>  10585
```

I only get one Pig_no with the data from df2, and not the rows from df2 divided out on all pigs in df1.

I want the merged dataframe to look like this, for all pens with treatments:

```
Pen       Date   Treat_date  Pig_no 
1   1 03.01.2020 15.01.2020  10555     
2   1 03.01.2020 15.01.2020  10560     
3   1 03.01.2020 15.01.2020  10583     
4   1 03.01.2020 15.01.2020  10585
```

Comment: `merge(df1[!is.na(df1$Treat_date), ], df2, all.x=TRUE)`?

Comment: I think remove `Date` from your `by` argument.